# ¿Cómo obtener la altura del statusbar en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Cómo se puede obtener la altura del statusbar de Android?

mediante XML para especificar con el valor `?android...` y por código Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un método:

```
Rect rectangle = new Rect();
Window window = getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
int contentViewTop = 
    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int alturaStatusBar = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;
```

Yo recomiendo este método, si requieres leer los valores desde `dimens.xml`, dependiendo de la densidad del dispositivo, por experiencia te comento que sería una pesadilla cuando desees realizar mantenimiento a tu application.

Esta es una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410200/250260) que realicé en el sitio SO en inglés:

De acuerdo a los [Android Design Guidelines](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs) la altura de una "Status Bar" es 24dp.

Comment: bueno visto que no encuentro el valor del atributo, lo que intento es hacer una barra de estado que se situé abajo de un EditText queria que tuviese el tamaño de la statusbar de Android. Normalmente que es 20dp?
También he encontrado eso
http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/

Comment: De acuerdo a los Android Design Guidelines la altura de una "Status Bar" es 24dp. =)